# What does (a ^ (1 << b)) actually do, in a language like C++?

Tags: java, c++, c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm looking at this function,

```
int func(int a, int b){
    return (a ^ (1 << b)); 
}
```

What is actually going on? I understand that it's basically saying, " a XOR (2^b) ", that is, a xor 2 to the power of b. But beyond that what is actually happening, and why? I guess I'm looking for some sort of pattern in this formula.

Comment: Why include a java tag if you are asking a question on c++? Why not write the rest of the code and run the program using a debugger so you can see what happens ?

Comment: Because this is just basic bit manipulation, it'd work in Java, C, whatever. And I've tried some tests and I can't see a pattern in it.

Comment: What do you mean, "beyond that what is actually happening?"? It computes a xor 2 to the power of b... that's all there is. I know that `a + (b / 5)` computes a added to b divided by 5, but beyond that what is actually happening and why?

Comment: Consider this, 1 << b is just byte shifting 1 by b.. but at a higher level we can see that it's just "2 to the power of b". I'm looking for some sort of thing like that, but for this entire formula.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This particular expression toggles the b-th bit of a.

This could be useful for example if you want to treat your `int` as a boolean array (or a bitmask), and negate the entry at position b.

Comment: I guess a followup question, why would this be useful?

Comment: ... for some definition of genius.. It is really "basic bit manipulation", as you say.

Comment: Right, but you actually caught what was going on pretty quickly. I did a for loop and printed out the results both in binary and base 10 and was staring at it for awhile and couldn't see what was staring me in the face. But there has to be a real use for this. Any idea?

Comment: FWIW, @SomeSortofGuy, the easier way to do this in C++ is `std::bitset`, where you can go `someBitset.flip(b);`.